# How to align a Text and Icon Composable so that they stay together even after text overflow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a Text and an Icon composable. I want the icon to stick to the right of composable. This is the code I have:

```kotlin
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = subjectName,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

The corresponding UI is:
[image]

This looks fine but when the text is too long and there is an overflow, the icon gets out of the screen like this:
[image]

Instead I want to make it look like this:
[image]

I tried giving the `Text` composable a `weight(1f)` modifier so that the Icon is placed first. Now it looks fine with overflown text, but when text is shorter, the Icon is still placed at the end because the Text is occupying the entire remaining width:

[image]

How can I get the desired UI (image 1 & 3) here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just apply the `weight(1f, fill=false)` modifier to the `Text`.

> When fill is `true`, the element will be forced to occupy the whole width allocated to it. Otherwise, the element is allowed to be smaller - this will result in Row being smaller, **as the unused allocated width will not be redistributed to other siblings.**

Something like:

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = "subjectName",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false),
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    )
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Add,
        contentDescription = "contentDescription"
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never noticed the `fill` parameter before.

Comment: Its not working when icon sticky at end with addition row.

Comment: @KishoreJethava What does it mean addition row? If your case is different open a new question. Someone will help you.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes